# Is the tensor algebra a Lie algebra?

Tags: lie-algebras, tensors

I found that the reverse is true. To show that it is a Lie algebra I just have to show that the Jacobi identity holds, so I was wontering if it could be true either for the tensor algebra of a vector space or for a subalgebra of that space.

Comment: "Reverse" of what? -- Being a Lie algebra is a structure, not a property. You can ask if a certain bracket defines a Lie algebra, but then you have to say what bracket you mean. Otherwise, every vector space "is" a Lie algebra when you set $[v,w] = 0$ for all vectors $v,w$.

Comment: That being said, if $A$ is *any* associative algebra with multiplication $a \cdot b$, then the bracket $[a,b] := a\cdot b-b\cdot a$ defines a Lie algebra structure on $A$. That's a standard fact / exercise with a staightforward proof that only needs some calculation and use of associativity (of $\cdot$) for the Jacobi identity (of $[\; , \;]$). Since the tensor algebra is an associative algebra, you can apply this.

Comment: Thank you, it was very helpful. So is this a way to always "construct" a Lie algebra given a vector space V?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Torsten says in the comments, every associative algebra is a Lie algebra with bracket the commutator bracket $[a, b] = ab - ba$.

The tensor algebra $T(V)$, as a Lie algebra, has a subalgebra generated by $V$ (which is not all of $T(V)$), and $T(V)$ has a special relationship to this subalgebra: at least in characteristic $0$, it is precisely the [universal enveloping algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_enveloping_algebra) of this subalgebra, and moreover this subalgebra is the [free Lie algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_Lie_algebra) $L(V)$ on $V$. This mostly follows from the fact that the two have the same universal property, except that there's a little work to be done explaining why the natural map $L(V) \to U(L(V))$ is injective. But this follows from the [Poincare-Birkhoff-Witt theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poincar%C3%A9%E2%80%93Birkhoff%E2%80%93Witt_theorem).

Comment: I think all these statements also hold in characteristic $p$, as the PBW theorem holds over every field.

Comment: @Jendrik: huh, I had the impression that it failed in characteristic $p$ for some reason... hmm.